# How can I add a blur effect to a background in an app?

Tags: android, filter, background, drawable, blur

**How can I add a blur effect to a background in an Android app? I would like to know some source with the resources and the steps to add this effect.** I understand that I have to add a filter, but I don't know where I am going to add it Please can someone help me? I will put the layout of the section that I want to change, As you can see, it has a normal background, but I want to put the blur effect on that section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use RenderScript to blur the Bitmap of image:

```
public Bitmap blurBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,Context context){
    //Let's create an empty bitmap with the same size of the bitmap we want to blur
    Bitmap outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Instantiate a new Renderscript
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    //Create an Intrinsic Blur Script using the Renderscript
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blurScript = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        blurScript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        //Create the Allocations (in/out) with the Renderscript and the in/out bitmaps
        Allocation allIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap);
        Allocation allOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outBitmap);
        //Set the radius of the blur
        blurScript.setRadius(25.f);
        //Perform the Renderscript
        blurScript.setInput(allIn);
        blurScript.forEach(allOut);
        //Copy the final bitmap created by the out Allocation to the outBitmap
        allOut.copyTo(outBitmap);
    }
    //recycle the original bitmap
    bitmap.recycle();
    //After finishing everything, we destroy the Renderscript.
    rs.destroy();
    return outBitmap;
}

public Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int heigh = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, heigh);
    Bitmap.Config config = drawable.getOpacity() != PixelFormat.OPAQUE ? Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            : Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, heigh, config);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

 public void blurImage(View imageView, Context context){
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getBackground();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
    Bitmap out = blurBitmap(bitmap,context);
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),
            out);
    imageView.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
}
```

Use it with a view id is view in a Activity:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.view);
blurImage(view,this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some libraries for you:

1. https://github.com/Manabu-GT/EtsyBlur
2. https://github.com/Manabu-GT/GlassView

Usually, we call this feature **Glass View**, so you can also google it.